# How deployment works with Airflow?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm using the Celery Executor and the setup from this [dockerfile](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow).

I'm deploying my dag into `/usr/local/airflow/dags` directory into the scheduler's container.

I'm able to run my dag with the command:

```
$ docker exec airflow_webserver_1 airflow backfill mydag -s 2016-01-01 -e 2016-02-01
```

My dag contains a simple bash operator:

```
BashOperator(command = "test.sh" ... )
```

The operator runs the `test.sh` script.

However if the `test.sh` refers to other files, like `callme.sh`, then I receive a "cannot find file" error.

```
e.g
$ pwd
/usr/local/airflow/dags/myworkflow.py

$ ls
myworkflow.py
test.sh
callme.sh

$ cat test.sh
echo "test file"
./callme.sh

$ cat callme.sh
echo "got called"
```

When running myworkflow, the task to call test.sh is invoked but fails for not finding the callme.sh.

I find this confusing. Is it my responsibility to share the code resource files with the worker or airflow's responsibility? If it's mine, then what is the recommended approach to do so? I'm looking at using EFS with it mounted on all container but it looks very expensive to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For celery executor, it is your responsibility to make sure that each worker has all the files it needs to run a job.